# How to randomly assign group based on count/repeat in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

All, I am trying to randomly assign groups (column F) based on "Count" and "Group" column (B and A)  and been having some trouble finding the right formula and would appreciate some pointers.

Screenshot below shows, a sample output in column F. Here, you may see Group A is assigned 4 times and B is assigned 6 times randomly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in F2 and drag down:

`IF(AND(RAND()<0.5,COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$A$2)<$B$2),$A$2,IF(COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$A$3)>=$B$3,$A$2,$A$3))`